# Where would I start if I wanted to make this?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to make a script that automatically opens up a web page, and inputs a certain text in a certain area or box and then hit start. (I am trying to make my life easier so I don't have to type in numbers every 10 mins.)

I don't really know where to start other than this:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('google.com') # for example.
# the following code is just of an example of what I mean
input.numbers('blahblahblah')
hit.enter
```

Something along those lines, I just need someone to point me in the right direction.
Thanks so much!

Comment: look into mechanize, requests and selenium

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to choose from.

The choice really depends on how easy it is to simulate the underlying request(s) going to the server when you hit "start", is there javascript, AJAX involved into the page load, button click etc.  If you don't want to dive into the implementation and you are ok with using real browser, when take a look at [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) package. Basically, through the python code you would tell the browser what to do: enter text into the text fields, click buttons etc - high level approach. Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

textfield = driver.find_element_by_id('gbqfq')
textfield.send_keys('selenium tutorial')

button = driver.find_element_by_id('gbqfba')
button.click()

# TODO: parse the results
```

Other tools to consider:

- [mechanize](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize)
- [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)
- [robobrowser](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser)
- [mechanicalsoup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup)

It is really difficult to tell you more since you are not specific about the task.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a HTML form post. The first thing you should ask yourself is if you really need to interact with the browser in order to accomplish your goal. It sounds to me like you don't need to, and in that case, something like the following code will perform a DuckDuckGo search automatically and display the results on the console.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/'
data = urllib.urlencode({'q': 'python 3'})
results = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)

print(results.read())
```

You can easily extrapolate this code to make it work with google...